# Как проверить поля data class на null и в зависимости от результата присвоить значения полей в переменную?

Tags: kotlin

Имеется класс данных:

```
data class LoginResponse(
    val accost: String? = null,
    val name: String? = null,
    val fullname: String? = null,
)
```

Данные в класс поступают из сервиса, поля необязательные для заполнения. Стоит задача проверить все поля на null и в случае, если поле не пустое и не является null присвоить его в переменную:

```
var accost = "друг"
```

Переменная в дальнейшем будет использоваться для приветствия пользователя. На данный момент реализация следующая:

```
 if(!LoginResponse.accost.isNullOrEmpty())
     accost = LoginResponse.data.accost
 else if (!LoginResponse.name.isNullOrEmpty())
         accost = LoginResponse.data.name
      else if(!LoginResponse.fullname.isNullOrEmpty())
              accost = LoginResponse.data.fullname

 Toast.makeText("$accost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Полей в data class на самом деле достаточно много, хочется получить более красивый и читаемый код.

В Kotlin имеется замечательный оператор `when(условие)` возможно ли его как то применить к данной ситуации?

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Вы хотите задним числом поменять поле в data class'e?

Comment: Нет, поправил вопрос, надеюсь стало более понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
acost = when {
    !LoginResponse.accost.isNullOrEmpty() -> LoginResponse.data.accost
    !LoginResponse.name.isNullOrEmpty() -> LoginResponse.data.name
    !LoginResponse.fullname.isNullOrEmpty() -> LoginResponse.data.fullname
    else -> "ААААА!!! ВСЕ ПРОПАЛО!!!"
}
```